# How to add server property to NextResponse? Nextjs Beta 13.2.3

Tags: next.js, server, socket.io, beta

I had a Nextjs project with socket.io I did the socket this way:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { Server } from 'socket.io'

import type { Server as HTTPServer } from 'http'
import type { Socket as NetSocket } from 'net'
import type { Server as IOServer } from 'socket.io'

export interface SocketServer extends HTTPServer {
  io?: IOServer | undefined
}

export interface SocketWithIO extends NetSocket {
  server: SocketServer
}

export interface NextApiResponseWithSocket extends NextApiResponse {
  socket: SocketWithIO
}

export default async function socketHandler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponseWithSocket
) {
  // It means that socket server was already initialised
  if (res.socket?.server.io) {
    console.log('Already set up')
    res.end()
    return
  }

  const io = new Server(res.socket.server)
  res.socket.server.io = io

  // Define actions inside
  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('New client connected')

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('Client disconnected')
    })

    socket.on('remoteControl', (event: any) => {
      io.emit('remoteControl', event)
    })
  })

  console.log('Setting up socket')
  res.end()
}
```

I'm starting a new project with the new routes APIs in the beta version. It doesn't have a handler, it comes this way:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  return NextResponse.json({succeed: true})
}
```

You export the method you want: GET, POST, etc. And uses NextResponse to return the answer to the client. How can I add NextResponse.server.socket.io to the new way to handle API routes.

I tried creating a extending type with the new properties I need.

```
import { Server as NetServer, Socket } from 'net'
import type { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { Server as SocketIOServer } from 'socket.io'

export type NextApiResponseServerIO = NextResponse & {
  socket: Socket & {
    server: NetServer & {
      io?: SocketIOServer;
    };
  };
};
```

But this only export a type, how do I convert NextResponse variable to this new type. Or any other way to keep the socket and server living with Next js.

Comment: DId you figure this out? Currently having the same problem. :(

Comment: Hi, no :( but. On app dir you can still use the page directory and use the old code. So I figure I'll use api/socket on page directory only. But for some reason it didn't work, the socket was able to start when I hit the api but the client wasn't able to connect to the socket server. I end up creating the server in another port. Was my last resort.